# jQuery show content by removing hidden class layout bug in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have content that is shown or hidden by adding or removing a class with jQuery which has display none applied to it with CSS.

This is working fine in all browsers except IE7. IE7 is showing and hiding the content but when shown (its hidden on page load) it goes underneath the content below it.

If I remove the styling from the class so nothing is hidden on page load then it doesn't go underneath and instead it displays properly as expected.

Comment: can you supply a link at all? It may be that you need to apply a float on the element you're hiding.

Comment: It would be great if you can show atleast some of the html/js code

Comment: Have you tried changing the z-index? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by making the element below it position relative with CSS.